# Exit PHP from the CLI OSX

Tags: php, macos, command-line-interface

First of all, I am an EXTREMELY newbie in the PHP world.
So I wanted to run a PHP web site in OSX installing [php liip](http://php-osx.liip.ch/).

After that, I went to my terminal and I just type `php` (just to see what happends), but it opens a kind of text editor that I cant exit:

[image: my cli]

How can I close such thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to exit.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody with linux and the same queestion could be sent here by google. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ([interrupt signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT) SIGINT) would not always kill a running job. Try

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> - ([quit signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGQUIT) SIGQUIT)

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> - sends ^\

```
$ php ...

^\Quit
```

which is equivalent to `kill -3 pid` - kill the process that is currently in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
It will send `EOF` (End Of File) symbol to PHP. In the case you are going to write there some script - when you done - do the same. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  will send `EOF` symbol to PHP and your input to PHP will be treated as finished.
However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as mentioned above would works also in the case you just want to exit PHP and discard anything you typed there. This combination sends `SIGINT` signal to current foreground process (php in your case) makes it quits immediately.